# Why does the syntax error in my dictionary point to the ":" and suggest to use a comma?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm following a tutorial where I need to write a dictionary:

```
from classes.game import Person, bcolors

magic = [{"name: Fire", "cost": 10, "dmg": 60},
         {"name: Thunder", "cost": 10, "dmg": 60},
         {"name: Blizzard", "cost": 10, "dmg": 60}]

player = Person(460, 65, 60, 34, magic)
enemy = Person(1200, 65, 45, 25, magic)
```

in line 3 there is a syntax error:

```
    magic = [{"name: Fire", "cost": 10, "dmg": 60},
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why does it point to the colon (`:`) after `"cost"`? Pycharm says it expects a comma, however that further causes issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake was that you wrote `"name: Fire"` instead of `"name": "Fire"`.

Besides dictionaries, there is another kind of collection in Python that are written with `{}`, but without `:`:

```
names = {"Fire", "Thunder", "Blizzard"}
```

These are called [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets).

By writing

```
{"name: Fire", "cost": 10, "dmg": 60}
```

Python (or Pycharm) thought you meant to write a set, consisting of the string `"name: Fire"`, and then the string `"cost"`. But then there was a `:` which does not occur in a set. So that's where they thought you made a mistake, even if your mistake was already earlier in that line.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is off:

```py
magic = [{"name": "Fire", "cost": 10, "dmg": 60},
         {"name": "Thunder", "cost": 10, "dmg": 60},
         {"name": "Blizzard", "cost": 10, "dmg": 60}]
```

The syntax on a dictionary is `"key": value`. You had `"key:value"`.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote `"name: Fire"`, which presumably should be `"name": "Fire"`.

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting to put quotes dividing the "name" key and values.

```py
from classes.game import Person, bcolors

magic = [{"name": "Fire", "cost": 10, "dmg": 60},
         {"name": "Thunder", "cost": 10, "dmg": 60},
         {"name": "Blizzard", "cost": 10, "dmg": 60}]
#              ^  ^

player = Person(460, 65, 60, 34, magic)
enemy = Person(1200, 65, 45, 25, magic)
```